# How to use Spring Hateoas properly with custom page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-hateoas

Consider this implementation that uses Spring HATEOAS.

```
@Controller
class PersonController {

  @Autowired PersonRepository repository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  HttpEntity<PagedResources<Person>> persons(Pageable pageable, 
    PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {

    Page<Person> persons = repository.findAll(pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(assembler.toResources(persons), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

I don't want to use:

```
repository.findAll(pageable);
```

Because I have another custom method that returns:

```
List<Person> persons = repository.findAll(new PersonSpec(personSpec));
```

What I have to do to have a "Page" from a "List" ?

Thanks

Comment: Just return `Page<Person>` from your find all method and pass your spec together with the `pageable`. What is your `PersonSpec` anyway?

Comment: it is a class that implements org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification, I have Specification<Person>

Comment: Then use the `findAll(specification, pageable)` method. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-